# timer1 hangs while other process occurs in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am using a timer1 with interval of 1 millisecond to generate time (hr,min,secs,millisecs) in a textbox.

Now whenever I receive value serially. i'll have to write data serially which will make 3 led turn on with a delay of 1 sec between each. I am using a textbox to display text like `Output 1 ON` & `Output 2 ON` with time. So that I can actually know at what time they are turning on.

But the problem is when the led's are turning ON, the timer hangs at that moment so as a result doesn't shows up the exact time at which the led's turned on.

My application need to show the time at every led turning on.

CODE: (timer)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 dateTime = DateTime.Now;
 time = dateTime.Hour + ":" + dateTime.Minute + ":" + dateTime.Second + ":" + dateTime.Millisecond;
 date = Convert.ToString(dateTime.Day + "/" + dateTime.Month + "/" + dateTime.Year);
 textBox2.Text = time;
 textBox1.Text = date;
}
```

CODE: (serial transmit/receive)

```
String data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
if (data == "11")
{
   textBox4.AppendText(time + " Input 1 HIGH\n");
   textBox4.AppendText("\n");
   button11.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    serialPort1.WriteLine("1");
    textBox4.AppendText(time + " Output 1 HIGH\n");

     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     serialPort1.WriteLine("2");
     textBox4.AppendText(time + " Output 2 HIGH\n");

      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      serialPort1.WriteLine("3");
      textBox4.AppendText(time + " Output 2 HIGH\n");
  }
```

I am new to winforms so don't have an idea. But I am ready to learn.
What can I use so that my timer doesn't hang during turning on of led's

Comment: How do you create the timer? What timer are you using?

Comment: I am using the design timer which I drag and drop it from toolbox

Comment: How are you executing the second snippet of code? Are you using threads at all?

Comment: Yes using `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` for received data but nothing for transmitting

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your serial transmit/receive code in a separate thread. Currently your whole application runs in 1 thread, so when you call Thread.Sleep() your whole application hangs, since every control is waiting for Thread.Sleep to end.

Concider using some kind of multi-threaded approach for your application.
For instance and simple implementation you can look at BackgroundWorker class:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: I got the idea of background worker but how can I use it for timer.

Comment: Backgroundworker should be used for your serial transmit/receive code, not for the timer.